# Not equal/not contains operation in lambda expressions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, linq

My query is some thing like:

```
var subQuery = contacts_requests.Where(i => i.requests_usr_id >= 1).Select          
           (i => i.Usr_contacts_requests_from_usr_id ).ToArray();
var query = biographic_details.Join(profiles_companies, i => i.usr_id, j => j.company_usr_id,
           (i,j)=>new{
                      Usr_bio_usr_id }).where(p=>subQuery.Contains(i.company_usr_id)).ToArray();
```

I want notcontains operation in place of contains, how can I implement that?

Comment: Do you want replace Contains to !Contains or what? What is a purpose of it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of

```
p => subQuery.Contains(i.company_usr_id)
```

use

```
p => !subQuery.Contains(i.company_usr_id)
```

Note the `!` before the method call. The `!` operator (aka [Logical negation operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2)) just negates the result of the following expression. So `Contains` becomes `Not Contains`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve not contains you can use `!subQuery.Contains(i.company_usr_id)`.